# Error opening URL

Tags: actionscript

Error opening URL 'http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml' - что это?

Comment: у меня работает, грузит хмл

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
    "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

   <cross-domain-policy>
     <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
    </cross-domain-policy>

Comment: это в Flash. я хз почему.

Comment: Например потому что атрибут 'secure="false"' разрешен только для https.